# Ошибка "unterminated string literal" в условие

Tags: php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM players");
$countPlayers = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($countPlayers[0] >= 10){
  $table = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10");
}
```

Вот кусок кода, в строке, где начинается if и выдаёт ошибку `unterminated string literal`.

Переменная `$countPlayers`:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "32" ["COUNT(1)"]=> string(2) "32" }
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: $countPlayers[0] и $countPlayers  - что выдает ? если  вывести через var_dump()

Comment: @Даниил `array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "32" ["COUNT(1)"]=> string(2) "32" } `

Comment: @epsilon попробуйте изменить запрос так: `"SELECT COUNT(*) AS all FROM players"` И далее в условии вместо `$countPlayers[0]` использовать ассоц.массив `$countPlayers['all']`

Comment: @Эдуард $countPlayers null получается

Comment: @Даниил ничего не поменялось

Comment: @epsilon а код можете показать?

Comment: @Эдуард `$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS all FROM players");
  $countPlayers = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if ($countPlayers['all'] >= 10)`

Comment: @epsilon тут парсер съедает апострофы, надо вот так: [смотреть код](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9e3ff749c64a0dbf2c3b8616b7cc8656baf8a91)

Comment: `unterminated string literal` это ошибка уровня javascript. Чего вы нам тут php-код-то показываете?